# read stdin in function in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, bash-function

I have some set of bash functions which output some information:

- **find-modelname-in-epson-ppds**
- **find-modelname-in-samsung-ppds**
- **find-modelname-in-hp-ppds**
- etc ...

I've been writing functions which read output and filter it:

```
function filter-epson {
    find-modelname-in-epson-ppds | sed <bla-blah-blah>
}

function filter-hp {
    find-modelname-in-hp-ppds | sed <the same bla-blah-blah>
}
etc ...
```

But the I thought that it would be better do something like this:

```
function filter-general {
    (somehow get input) | sed <bla-blah-blah>
}
```

and then call in another high-level functions:

```
function high-level-func {
    # outputs filtered information
    find-modelname-in-hp/epson/...-ppds | filter-general 
}
```

How can I achieve that with the best bash practices?

Comment: If you're looking for good practice, you can already replace `function fname` with `fname()`.

Comment: What's the difference? Only the brevity? But I think definition with `function` looks more expressive, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by _more expressive_? In [this link](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) you'll see that it's obsolete and deprecated (and not POSIX).

Comment: What do your functions `find-modelname-...` really look like and do? Maybe you should tell us more so that we can advice the best option. You're clearly trying to factor some pieces of code, but we need to know what it is exactly.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the link you reference says `function fname { ... }` is fine. What's deprecated is `function fname() {...}`

Comment: @bames53 `function` [is not defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes, but it's not deprecated in bash as you indicated. Anyway the paren syntax is uglier and doesn't make sense; They aren't used to call the function and one doesn't pass parameters inside them.

Comment: @bames53 ok, then use it as much as you want `;)`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If the question is `How do I pass stdin to a bash function?`, then the answer is:

Shellscript functions take stdin the ordinary way, as if they were commands or programs. :)

input.txt:

```
HELLO WORLD
HELLO BOB
NO MATCH
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

myfunction() {
    grep HELLO
}

cat input.txt | myfunction
```

Output:

```
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch$ ./test.sh 
 HELLO WORLD 
 HELLO BOB
```

Note that command line arguments are ALSO handled in the ordinary way, like this:

test2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

myfunction() {
    grep "$1"
}

cat input.txt | myfunction BOB
```

Output:

```
hobbes@metalbaby:~/scratch/$ ./test2.sh 
 HELLO BOB
```

Comment: This does not work on bash 4.1.0. I get the output:  " HELLO WORLD \n HELLO BOB \n NO MATCH"

Comment: Ok, it's because of my usage of `\n` in the input string. I've edited the answer; it now just cats an input file, for the sake of simplicity.  This question is about accessing `stdin` from a function--and that part works even in bash 2.05b. :)

Comment: Ah, yes... because echo does not support escape sequences. Another way to handle that is define a variable like NL="<hit Enter here>" and replace "\n" with "$NL". Working now. Thanks!

Comment: This makes no sense for a multi-command function. E.g., assign a variable and then invoke a command that takes stdin following. Or what if I want to pass the stdin to two different functions (à la `tee`)? The lack of explanation here makes this answer virtually useless if you don't already know the answer and have an even *slightly* more complex case.

Comment: jpmc26, hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I hope this answer isn't really 'virtually useless'.  The question is about the simple case, so the answer is about the simple case, too.  I've never tried to pipe `stdin` to a function that contains more than one command.  I'll play with that idea in my shell later.  Meanwhile, if you have time, please post a new question about that.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the downvote! Apparently I mis-clicked the button two days ago (instead of upvoting it), and now I cannot revert my vote until the answer is edited once.

Answer (score 37):

To be painfully explicit that I'm piping from stdin, I sometimes write

```
cat - | ...
```

Comment: In my case, indeed I needed to be "painfully explicit", otherwise it didn't work.

Comment: @Mahdi What do you mean? Are there shells out there which require the use of `cat -` in this case/context? Which? When? How?

Comment: I have a script that runs as a mapper in a Hadoop map-reduce job, and the input contents are given to me via stdin. I needed to read the whole input into a file for further processing, and this solution worked for me.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. It is short, simple and most importantly, straight to the point. Basically, man page for `cat` recommends doing it just like that. Or just `cat | `, but that is less explicit.

Answer (score 35):

A **very simple** means to get stdin into a variable is to use `read`.  By default, it reads file descriptor "0", i.e. stdin i.e., `/dev/stdin`.

Example Function:

```
input(){ local in; read in; echo you said $in; }
```

Example implementation:

```
echo "Hello World" | input
```

Result:

> you said Hello World

#### Additional info

You don't need to declare a variable as being local, of course.  I just included that for the sake of good form.  Plain old `read in` does what you need.

So you understand how `read` works, by default it reads data off the given file descriptor (or implicit stdin) and **blocks** until it encounters a newline.  Much of the time, you'll find that will implicitly be attached to your input, even if you weren't aware of it.  If you have a function that seems to hang with this mechanism just keep this detail in mind (there are other ways of using `read` to deal with that...).

### More robust solutions

Adding on to the basic example, here's a variation that lets you pass the input via a stdin OR an argument:

```
input()
{ 
    local in=$1; if [ -z "$in" ]; then read in; fi
    echo you said $in
}
```

With that tweak, you could ALSO call the function like:

```
input "Hello World"
```

How about handling an stdin option plus **other arguments**?  Many standard nix utilities, especially those which typically work with stdin/stdout adhere to the common practice of treating a dash `-` to mean "default", which contextually means either stdin or stdout, so you can follow the convention, and treat an argument specified as `-` to mean "stdin":

```
input()
{ 
    local a=$1; if [ "$a" == "-" ]; then read a; fi
    local b=$2
    echo you said $a $b
}
```

Call this like:

```
input "Hello" "World"
```

or

```
echo "Hello" | input - "World"
```

Going even further, there is actually no reason to only limit stdin to being an option for only the *first* argument!  You might create a super flexible function that could use it for any of them...

```
input()
{ 
    local a=$1; if [ "$a" == "-" ]; then read a; fi
    local b=$2; if [ "$b" == "-" ]; then read b; fi
    echo you said $a $b
}
```

Why would you want that?  Because you could formulate, and pipe in, whatever argument you might need...

```
myFunc | input "Hello" -
```

In this case, I pipe in the 2nd argument using the results of `myFunc` rather than the only having the option for the first.

Comment: Coming to this answer from the future - your example will only read the first line of multi-line input streamed to the function - is there a better way to grab 'all 'of stdin and use it in a single variable?

Comment: Hi future reader!  Use the `-d` option for `read` to specify a different delimiter instead of the default newline.  See: https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you're attempting to do exactly, but if reading a file it would probably make sense to use `cat` instead of `read`.  If gathering directly typed input, you could prompt the user to end their text in some special character to denote the end of input.

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/a/783506

Comment: I ultimately ended up using cat - I was writing a 'logging library' for some of our bash scripts, and wanted a 'log_debug' type of method that could either take an argument OR have the result piped in.

Answer (score 6):

Call `sed` directly. That's it.

```
function filter-general {
    sed <bla-blah-blah>
}
```