# In a bash function, how do I get stdin into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to call a function with a pipe, and read all of stdin into a variable.

I read that the correct way to do that is with `read`, or maybe `read -r` or `read -a`. However, I had a lot of problems in practise doing that (esp with multi-line strings).

In the end I settled on

```
function example () {
  local input=$(cat)
  ...
}
```

### What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Do you need all of the input in a single string or do you need to operate on the pipe data in pieces?

Comment: have you tried something like `read -r -d\0 input` (assuming your input does not contain any null characters)? This will save one process per function call. I believe however that the `$(cat)` solution is more readable.

Comment: I think the idiomatic way to do this is to not do it.  Instead, read stdin instead of using the variable where you intend to use the variable.  If you need to reference the data multiple times, figure out a way to refactor the work so that is not necessary. How do you intend to use the variable?

Comment: @williamPursell I want to save this all up front because I want to do other things before processing it (such as calling other functions, declaring other vars, etc).

Comment: Unless the other things you plan on doing are going to consume standard input you can just do them first without worrying about `stdin` until you need it. And storing it in a variable will require storage memory for it all and consuming it all *before* your other work can even start.

Comment: What are you actually planning to do with the contents of `stdin`?

Comment: Questions about why you want to aside, this *is* the correct way to do it in those situations where you need/want to.

Comment: @etanreisner Unless I'm mistaken, in a bash function the stdin is passed to the first command in the function. This is why I "can't"  do the other things first. Would be happy to learn my assumption is broken and that I in fact can use stdin later, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: You are mistaken. stdin exists in the function with the data being piped in, all processes/commands run in the function share that stdin fd (unless otherwise redirected). The first command that reads from it will get the data. Try `f() { echo "foo"; echo "bar"; cat; }; printf %s\\n one two three | f` for example. (Also this is why you can run `read` multiple times in a loop to get data from stdin line-by-line, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @etanReiser, that clears things up a lot.

Comment: @MichaelJaros, `-d ''` or `-d $'\0'`; `-d\0` is wrong. (I'd argue that `-d ''` is _least wrong_; `-d $'\0'` is misleading about how bash works, implying that it can represent a NUL literal inside a string when it can't actually do that)

Answer (score 15):

`input=$(cat)` is a perfectly fine way to capture standard input if you really need to. One caveat is that command substitutions strip all trailing newlines, so if you want to make sure to capture those as well, you need to ensure that something aside from the newline(s) is read last.

```
input=$(cat; echo x)
input=${input%x}   # Strip the trailing x
```

Another option in `bash` 4 or later is to use the `readarray` command, which will populate an array with each line of standard input, one line per element, which you can then join back into a single variable if desired.

```
readarray foo
printf -v foo "%s" "${foo[@]}"
```

Comment: According to [SC5145](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2145), one should use `foo[*]` instead of `foo[@]` in a string. 

Comment: @lindhe, is "in a string" accurate anywhere here? `printf` takes an arbitrary number of arguments and repeats the format string as many times as necessary to consume them, so `foo=( one two three ); printf -v str %s "${foo[@]}"` will assign `str=onetwothree`, whereas with `"${foo[*]}"` it would be `str='one two three'` (with a default IFS).

Answer (score 10):

I've found that using `cat` is really slow in comparison to the following method, based on tests I've run:

```
local input="$(< /dev/stdin)"
```

In case anyone is wondering, `<` is just input redirection. From the bash-hackers [wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities) (*[new link](https://bash-hackers.gabe565.com/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities) until [fixed](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/12klulf/bashhackersorg_is_now_a_parking_domain/)*):

> When the inner command is only an input redirection, and nothing else,
> for example
>
> ```
> $( <FILE )
> # or
> ` <FILE `
> ```
>
> then Bash attempts to read the given file and act just if the given
> command was `cat FILE`.

---

#### Remarks about portability

In terms of how portable this method is, you are likely to go your entire linux user career, and never use a linux system which doesn't have `/dev/stdin`, but in case you want to satisfy that itch, here is a [question on Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/how-portable-are-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-and-dev-stderr) which questions portability of directly accessing `/dev/{stdin,stdout,stderr}` and friends.

One more thing I've come across when working with *containers* - such as ones built with docker, or buildah - is that there are situations where `/dev/stdin` or even `/dev/stdout` are not available inside the container. I've not been able to conclusively say what causes this, but I believe this answer may be found in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438/264812.

Comment: Amazing! Care to explain how `<` inside `$()` works?

Comment: @TeddyC I just update the answer with an explanation

Comment: See [What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438/264812).

Comment: indeed, as described in that linked post, something like `bash -c 'read x; input="$(< /dev/stdin)"; echo "$input"' < test.txt` would print the whole of `test.txt` on Linux, while the same with `$(cat)` prints only from the position after `read` read the first line. Of course you don't get that issue when reading from a pipe, so that's one case where `cat test.txt | bash ...` is not useless..

Answer (score -1):

There are a few overlapping / very similar questions floating around on SO.  I answered this here, using the `read` built-in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452863/3220983

In my answers there, however, I am ONLY concerned with a **single** line.

**The arguable weakness of the `cat` approach, is that requires spawning a subshell.**  Otherwise, it's a good one.  It's probably the easiest way to deal with multi line processing, as specifically queried here.

I *think* the `read` approach is faster / more resource efficient if you are trying to chain a lot of commands, or iterate through a list calling a function repeatedly.